# Applying same CSS across different areas of code - divs and classes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to ensure that all of my code shares the same style rules. AAt the moment, my last few divs will not respond to the css of the rest of the website, and I'm not sure why this is.

I've deleted additional html/body tags to ensure that all code is included within one set - in the practise.html file. I'm not sure what else to do.

```css
html {
  font-size: 8px;
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/3sKpysu.jpg) center;
  background-size: 2590x1730;
}

body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.keys {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.key {
  border: .4rem solid black;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1rem .5rem;
  transition: all .07s ease;
  width: calc((100% / 3) - 4rem);
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background: rgba(0, 1, 3, 0.4);
  text-shadow: 0 0 .5rem black;
}

.playing {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  border-color: #ffc600;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1rem #ffc600;
}

kbd {
  display: block;
  font-size: 4rem;
}

.sound {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
  color: #ffc600;
}

.movieButton {
  border: .4rem solid black;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  padding: 1rem .5rem;
  transition: all .07s ease;
  width: calc((100% / 3) - 4rem);
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background: rgba(0, 1, 3, 0.4);
  text-shadow: 0 0 .5rem black;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.slogan {
  border: .4rem solid black;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  padding: 1rem .5rem;
  transition: all .07s ease;
  width: calc((100% / 3) - 4rem);
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background: rgba(0, 1, 3, 0.4);
  text-shadow: 0 0 .5rem black;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.MovieDisplay {
  border: .4rem solid black;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  padding: 1rem .5rem;
  transition: all .07s ease;
  width: calc((100% / 3) - 4rem);
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background: rgba(0, 1, 3, 0.4);
  text-shadow: 0 0 .5rem black;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Movies</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <title>Random Movies Generator</title>

  <div class="section-heading">
    <div class="home-section text-center bg-gray">

      <div class="slogan">
        <h2>Favourite Movies <span class="text_color">Generator</span> </h2>
        <h4>Connecting you to the best movies around</h4>
      </div>

      <p>Can't decide on a film? Try the random movies generator button below, which will give you a movie from <strong>IMDB's Top 250 movies</strong> list:</p>
      <br>
      <div id="MovieDisplay">
        <!--Thriller Movies will display here-->
      </div> <br />
      <button class="movieButton" onclick="newMovie()">Random Movie</button>

    </div>
    <script src="movies.js"></script>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "My javascript code will not respond to the css of the rest of the website"? JS doesn't usually respond to CSS. CSS just modifies the way the DOM is rendered. CSS doesn't care where the DOM came from, whether it's from HTML or JavaScript.

Comment: Please post the relevant code here, using [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) rather than at codepen.

Comment: Also, note it should be `<!DOCTYPE html>` and `<body>` should go after `</head>`.

Comment: OK, thank you. As you can see, I've got the stylesheet in the header tag, except some of my divs are not responding to it and I don't know why. Codepen is the easiest way for me to show this, as all the code is there.

Comment: @Barmar - I've changed the code - all the divs/classes you can see in the text do not respond to the styling in the stylesheet, although the rest of the site does. Can you tell me why?

Comment: @CatherineTranfield could you show style.css? Just the problematic part will suffice

Comment: Hi Catherine and welcome to SO. Please provide us with a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that it will be easier to identify your problem. Make sure to add all of your related code, including HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: @WellBloud yes, I'll add it now - but I'm not sure what the problematic part is exactly

Comment: @CatherineTranfield I'm still not sure what exactly is your problem. I edited your question and added previous HTML code, because we need it to see. Please try to provide more information about the problem - attach html code with the actual problem, screenshot if possible etc. Only thing I see right now is that you have `<div id="MovieDisplay">` but in CSS you have `.MovieDisplay` selector, which won't fit. Either change CSS selector to `#MovieDisplay` or add class `MovieDisplay` to the div

Comment: Just to point out `background-size: 2590x1730;` is not valid CSS, if you want to set the exact width/height you need something like `background-size: 2590px 1730px;`

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, you are setting `MovieDisplay` as a class, with the class identifier `.`, but in your HTML, this is actually an `id`.

On your `<div>`...

Change this: `id="MovieDisplay"`

To this: `class="MovieDisplay"`

**Edit**

As per your comment, you wish to keep the id. In this case, in your CSS...

Change this: `.MovieDisplay {...}`

To this: `#MovieDisplay {...}`

Comment: I have to keep it as an id because of the javascript

Comment: var quotes = [
  'The Dark Knight',
  'Inception',
  'The Departed',
  'Heat',
  'Leon: The Professional',
  'Black Swan',
  'Kill Bill: Vol 1',
  'The Dark Knight Rises',
  'The Silence of the Lambs',
  'Shutter Island',
  'The Godfather',
  'The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King',
  'Pulp fiction',
  'Schindlers List',
  'Fight Club',
  'Avengers End Game'

]

function newMovie() {
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (quotes.length));
  document.getElementById('MovieDisplay').innerHTML = quotes[randomNumber];
}

Comment: Well in that case then change the css class identifier to an id identifier `#`. So you new css rule would be `#MovieDisplay {...}` I'll edit my answer to reflect this.